# How do i acess textfields inside MC contained in a ScrollPane

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I have the following situation... I have a ScrollPane that has a movieclip contained. Inside that movieclip i have various textfields wich i want to populate with json. I know how to do the json part, so the real question here is how can i acess the textfield inside the movieclip??
I have tried the normal way :

```
scrollable.inf_rest.text = "Test;
```

Scrollable is my mc, and inf_rest my textbox but i gives me the error 1119:

```
1119: Access of possibly undefined property inf_rest through a reference with static type Class.
```

I also tried to do it inside the mc, and it's possible to change it but not with the json...
Any ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: You need to place the instance of our MC instead of `scrollable`, because `scrollable` is not "a" MC, it's the class of MCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myMovieClip, containing myTextField... `source` of myScrollPane:

```
myScrollPane.source = myMovieClip;
```

don't mean that you add myMovieClip as child of myScrollPane like that:

```
myScrollPane.addChild(myMovieClip);
```

myMovieClip isn't a `child` of myScrollPane, it's its `source`. If you try to call myMovieClip as a child of myScrollPane the error 1119 occurs:

```
trace(myScrollPane.myMovieClip); // error 1119
```

Simply consider that you modify your MovieClip's textField:

```
import fl.containers.ScrollPane; 

var myScrollPane:ScrollPane = new ScrollPane();
var myMovieClip:Mc = new Mc();
myMovieClip.myTextField.text = "hello world!";
myScrollPane.source = myMovieClip;
addChild(myScrollPane);
```

Comment: Thanks for the clean explanation, i now understand it and it works perfectly fine!
Thank you once again !